# URL Resolver in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I am working an application with classic ASP.

Now i want to know how to resolve the url path for the below code.

```
<!--#include file="../hf/headerfooter.asp"-->
```

This is used in many other pages nested in different folder. So i want to resolve this path according to it.

Is there any url helper method available for ASP for doing that? In ASP.Net we can do with ~ symbol or using [**Control.ResolveUrl() method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

How can done the same with Classic ASP.
Any input welcome to achive this functionlaity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<!--#include virtual="/hf/headerfooter.asp"-->
```

to include a file with a virtual path instead of a fixed/absolute path.
This will load the file relative to your site root.